# Other ways to return data other than string $_GET string parameters?

Tags: php, get, header, location, session-variables

So im asking what options do I have other than redirecting GET variables when Im trying to repopulate a form?

Im thinking I can create session variable and use that also. Am I correct that these are the ONLY 2 ways?

What I have now is:

```
if ( count($m) > 0 ) {    
// there is an error in fields filled out so we are sending user back to     form.
$_SESSION["myarray"] = $m;
header("location: ./edit.php?datefield=".$datefield."&text=".$entry."&flag=".$flag);    
}
```

but this reveals my variable to the user. I want to avoid this.

**UPDATE**
I re-worded my question and the code to be clearer.
I also like found that the solution for me was to use an include('edit-error.php'). Which is basically the original edit.php with everything stripped out but the code needed to generate the form, and I populated edit-error.php with the needed variables. I never had this in my tool box before so I am grateful to the user who suggested it.

Comment: so many ways. but why redirect when you could simply include the view and pre-populate the data in it?

Comment: @pala_4 I am not understanding what you mean by "simply include the view and pre-populate". Seems I HAVE to redirect BACK to page with form in order to do this right? Is there an example of this method you speak of?

Comment: you can `include('edit.php')`, and inside edit.php, you can look for variables that you have set to specify that there are errors, and also pre-fill form values with those already entered. instead of redirecting

Comment: Ahhh! I see what you mean now. This does give me some ideas. Let me play with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can consider for hide information (not totally, but more stronger than GET) of user is create a JSON with your infos and send a POST request to your page.

Personally, I still preferring sessions, but there are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was provided my user pala_ , so thanks pala_ I up voted your comment.

I used include('edit-error.php'). Which is basically the original edit.php with everything stripped out but the code needed to generate the form, and I populated edit-error.php's form with the needed variables. I never had this in my tool box before so I am grateful to the pala_ who suggested it.

This allows me to conduct server side validation and redisplay the form again with user input, so they can resubmit. I was using header(Location) with paramaters to submit as GET and I didnt want that. Using include() is a perfect solution for me.